# I got into a scam of front running bot

Tags: blockchain, pancakeswap, frontrunning

i got scammed few days back through a youtube video.
i did exactly as they said and send .15+.35 a total of .5 BNB.
I know i am the dumbest person but is there any way i can get my bnb back?
As i created the smart contract but through their code can anyone tell me any way out of it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: DId you report the video?

Comment: Why didnt you write in the comments?! I just got scammed .5 bnb just now too :(

Answer (score 2):

I hate to break it to you but your funds are lost. You deployed and funded a smart contract without understanding what its code does. By calling the "action" function of the smart contract, the funds stored on the contract where sent to the scammer's address. There is no way to get it back.